# Erro ao executar projeto default do springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pom

estou tentando executar o projeto default do springboot que eu adquiri [aqui](https://start.spring.io/). O projeto está com as seguintes dependências:

```
<groupId>br.com.fc</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>api</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Porém sempre que eu mando executar da esse erro:

```
***************************

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

***************************


Description:


Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no 
embedded datasource could be configured.


Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class




Action:


Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Alguém sabe o motivo?

Comment: Esta aplicação tem algum arquivo de properties ou yml? Exemplo: `application.yml`. Acredito que esteja faltando configurar o banco de dados e o erro esteja relacionado a falta da propriedade: `spring.datasource.url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar as configurações de acesso ao seu banco para que o Spring saiba como realizar a conexão. Isso pode ser feito programaticamente:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/nomedobanco");
    dataSource.setUsername("mysqluser");
    dataSource.setPassword("mysqlpass");

    return dataSource;
}
```

Ou através do seu arquivo de configuração `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/nomedobanco
spring.datasource.username=mysqluser
spring.datasource.password=mysqlpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Mesmo eu não tendo escrito uma linha de código sequer, eu preciso fazer essas configurações?

Comment: Então, para o mysql-connector-java sim, mas se fosse um H2 não precisaria: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

e so remover do pom a seguinte dependencia abaixo.

dependency>
org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

que ira funcionar, porque nao tem as configurações do banco.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).